# Overwrite Variable in Azure Yaml Pipeline not working

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

My intention is to run a pipeline with a default variable. The variable `createRelease` should indicate which job should run in addition to `TestApplication.

In pseudocode:

```
RunJob('TestApplication')

if(!createRelease) 
    RunJob('BuildForDev')

if(createRelease)
    RunJob('BuildForUatRelease')
```

Somehow it does not overwrite the value of `createRelease`. Anyone any Idea why not?

My Pipeline yaml looks like:

```
trigger:
- main
- feature/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:  
  - name: createRelease
    value: false

stages:
  - stage: CI_Build
    displayName: Build and Test App
    jobs:
      - job: TestApplication
        displayName: Building and testing
        condition: always()
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Maven Test Application
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo 'mvn test'
      - job: BuildForDev
        displayName: Build Application for Develop
        dependsOn: TestApplication
        condition: |
          and(
            succeeded('TestApplication'),
            eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'),
            eq(variables.createRelease, 'false')
          )
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Maven test Application
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo mvn test
      - job: BuildForUatRelease
        displayName: Release Application
        dependsOn: TestApplication
        condition: |
          and(
            succeeded('TestApplication'),
            eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main'),
            eq(variables.createRelease, 'true')
          )
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Set Git Credentials
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo 'mvn release prepare'
```

Variable definition in Pipeline which can be overwritten:

[image]

How I set the `createRelease` before run:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the value of the variable in the YAML which will take precedence over the variable defined at queue time. It might help to think of it like this:

- You queue the pipeline with the `createRelease: True` variable
- Azure DevOps creates an execution context for the pipeline and executes your pipeline.yml
- Your pipeline defines the value for `createRelease: False`

To resolve:

1. Remove the `createRelease` variable from the yaml
2. Edit the pipeline:

   [image]
3. Click on Variables:

   [image]
4. Add a new variable and set the default value for the createRelease variable. Set it to allow users to change the value at queue-time:

   [image]
5. Click Ok.

Alternatively, you might want to consider create a parameter instead of a variable:

```
trigger:

parameters:
- name: createRelease
  displayName: 'Create a Release'
  type: boolean
  default: false

stages:
- stage: ...
  jobs:
  - job: ...
    steps:
    - script: 'hello'
      condition: ${{ eq( parameters.createRelease, 'true') }}
```

Comment: I like the idea of using parameters, that is what I  was looking for. But when I do my condition in a job as you described within a script, first the job is skipped second how can I integrate it within an AND clause? THX for your feedback.

Comment: You can combine runtime and compile-time expressions:  `and( eq(variables['mine'], true), eq( '${{ parameters.createRelease }}', true) )